# WCF REST upload file

Tags: wcf

When server side obtain a zip data package from client side.I unzip this package and parse xml data to sql server.Then return success message to client side!

but I run into problem. I woluld like to return success message to client side in time when client uploaded success but not after inserted into data to database!

Can you help me ？tks in advance! sorry for my bad english!

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginAsyncUpload(string token, Stream data, string fileName, string Org, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        if (BaseClass.HasPermission(token))
        {
            return new CompletedAsyncResult<Stream>(data, fileName,Org);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public string EndAsyncUpload(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        Stream data = ((CompletedAsyncResult<Stream>)ar).Data;
        string fileName = ((CompletedAsyncResult<Stream>)ar).FileName;
        string Organization = ((CompletedAsyncResult<Stream>)ar).Org;
        try
        {
            return _streamToFile(data, fileName, Organization);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "SUCCESS！";
        }
    }
```

THE _streamToFile method insert data into db

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you can seperate your database insertion code and call that funcation asynchronously.

refer for asynch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164036.aspx

Second method is, store file in folder A, create seperate win service application to read files from same folder A, extract and insert into sql.Then move to folder B.